# C# - Add pictures on google maps?

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps

Im making a applictation that will need live tracking of virtual airplanes. I can get the latitude and longitude from a database but I need to place an image on a map to show where it is in real time. How would do this? I do not necessary need it to be google maps. I just need to place images on a special latitude and longitude on a map. Thank you!
Here is my code:

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"<html><head>
            <script type='text/javascript'  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXX&sensor=FALSE'></script>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    function initialize() {
                        var Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(25.252778000000000000, 55.364444000000050000)
                         var mapOptions = {
                         center: Latlng,
                         zoom: 10,
                         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                         marker: true
                     };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_name'), mapOptions);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: Latlng,
                    icon:'imag_real_time.png',
                    title: 'dubai airport'
                   });
                   marker.setMap(map);
                }
            </script>
            </head><body onload='initialize()'><div id='map_name' style='height='100px; width='100px;'></div></body></html>";
    }
```

Comment: How are you embedding google-maps in a Winforms application? Are you using the [WebBrowser Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: I havn't embeded it yet..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the pin in Google Maps with [custom markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers).

Answer (score 0):

**get the map api key use java script
set api key and sensor parameter either true or false for user(GPS) location**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Your_API_Key&sensor=SET_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
```

**using initialize() function and call in onload**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() {
 var Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(25.252778000000000000, 55.364444000000050000)
 var mapOptions = {
 center: Latlng,
 zoom: 10,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 marker: true
 };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_name"), mapOptions);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: Latlng,
 icon:'imag_real_time.png',
 title: "dubai airport"
 });
 marker.setMap(map);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Lovely answers but I need this in C# since I'm doing a winform applkcation

Comment: Nevermind, im an idiot. I've added this to my webbrowser but nothing comes up? I don't get any error but nothing comes upp..

Comment: Okey, now I get "Can't show google maps element on this website. The Google-API key is not allowed to be used on this website. I've made a api key but how do I add so it's allowed to run here since it's not a website, it's an application?

Comment: Yeah I just added it.